# AWS Application load balancer : time out on health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn, amazon-elb, aws-auto-scaling

I've built a website in Django that I'd like to promote using AWS Elastic Load Balancer (Application Load Balancer) coupled with an Auto Scaling Group.

For context: I'm using a VPC containing 2 public subnets linked to an internet gateway. I have an RDS database in a private subnet.

My site is developed and functional within an EC2 instance. I've configured Gunicorn to start automatically by creating a gunicorn.service file dont le contenu est le suivant :

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/datasource/src
Environment="SECRET_NAME_1=my_first_secret"
Environment="SECRET_NAME_2=my_second_secret"
Environment="SECRET_REGION_NAME=my_region"
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 datasource.wsgi:application --chdir /home/ec2-user/datasource/src

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Since the Amazon EC2 instances are on CentOS, for the Nginx configuration I had to create a sites-availables and sites-enabled folders in /etc/nginx/ and put the following configuration in it:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name datasource.fr www.datasource.fr;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I hadded in nginx.conf the following statement

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Then I runned these commands :

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/datasource.fr /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
sudo nginx -t

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

OK, I test directly on my EC2 instance by entering http://ipadress/ and it works: the site is fully accessible.

I therefore transform my instance into an AMI image and place it as an auto-scaling-group in a launch template.

Set up my auto-scaling group and my applicaiton load balancer, with the right security groups:

**Application load balancer:**

**Inbound rules :**

- Source 0.0.0.0/0 Port 80
- Source 0.0.0.0/0 Port 443

**Outbound rules:**

- Destination: auto-scaling-security-group, Port 80
- Destination: auto-scaling-security-group, Port 443
- Destination: auto-scaling-security-group, Port 8000

**Auto Scaling Group :**

**Inbound rules :**

- Source: elastic-load-balancer-security-group, Port 80
- Source: elastic-load-balancer-security-group, Port 443
- Sourcve: : elastic-load-balancer-security-group, Port 8000

**Outbound rules :**

- Destination: all traffic

Aaaaaaand nope. It doesn't work: the health-checks time out without me knowing why.

So I try to create an instance from the AMI image -> I can access it immediately via the IP address

I've followed the recommendation not to set public IP addresses as default for auto scaling group instances, so I try to create another auto scaling group with public IP addresses as default. Funny thing: I can access it immediately via the IP address, but the health check time out is still there.

I've changed the security groups by changing the origins and destinations to "all traffic" on the ports concerned, turning my instances into real sieves, I can still access them if I assign a public IP address, health check time out.

I'm completely out of ideas. The videos I see on the internet set up an auto scaling group with disconcerting simplicity, without even configuring a Nginx or Gunicorn server.

If you have any ideas, I'd love to hear from you.

Comment: What are the listeners configured on your load balancer ? You have to have a listener that will send the request to a target group. It looks like this information is missing from your question.

Comment: As a reference, we are also using an ALB with nginx and our server configuration is not using the `server_name` directive, only `listen 80 default_server;`. Maybe this is the problem since the domain name is irrelevent once the request has been handle by the load balancer.

Comment: Finally, if you are still having issue, may I recommand using Elastic Beanstalk to handle application deployment. It creates load balancer, listener and everything around it needed to have your app work properly. It might be worth it to check it out.

Comment: Hello Nicolas, thank you for your reply. I do have a target group, which is precisely where the "health check" doesn't work. So much so that if I have a public ip address, perfectly accessible with HTTP requests, the health checks time out despite the fact that the site is accessible. 

I've tried to modify my nginx configuration file as you suggested, but unfortunately I have the same problem. Out of curiosity, what are the incoming and outgoing rules of the security group of your ALB, as well as your ASG? I can only see one problem there.

I'll try Beanstalk if I can't find a solution.

Comment: As for our sg, for the loadbalancer: all traffic inbound for port 80 and 443, and all traffix outbound. For the instances, we have a rule for the port 80 comming from the sg of the load balancer, and all outbound traffic. That's it. Maybe the issue is with your loadbalancer outbound traffic. You don't really have to restrict it, you can leave all port open for all traffic.

Comment: Thank you, still not working hehe. Last question and i'll be done for today, do instances in your ASG have the "auto-assign public IP" option ? Or are they without public IP ?

Comment: They are in a private network so they don't need public ips. What's the port of your health check ? Since only the 80 port is opened on our instance, the health check have to be on port 80.

Comment: Same for me, port 80. I'm out of ideas, it is really strange. The fun fact is that if I put in the target group an instance with an Elastic IP Adress (so no auto scaling group), the DNS on the load balancer works and I can access the website, and the health checks still fails. But it's pointless because I can't use the ASG, so no scalability.